# How can I validate an email address from a specific domain?

Tags: javascript, validation, email

I have this code to validate email input. My problem is, I want my form to accept only one specific domain. Such as, for example, test@thisdomainonly.com. I have no idea how to do this. Here's what I have so far:

```
function validateEmail(email)
{
    var splitted = email.match("^(.+)@(.+)$");
    if (splitted == null) return false;
    if (splitted[1] != null)
    {
        var regexp_user = /^\"?[\w-_\.]*\"?$/;
        if (splitted[1].match(regexp_user) == null) return false;
    }
    if (splitted[2] != null)
    {
        var regexp_domain = /^[\w-\.]*\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/;
        if (splitted[2].match(regexp_domain) == null)
        {
            var regexp_ip = /^\[\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\]$/;
            if (splitted[2].match(regexp_ip) == null) return false;
        } // if
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How about a simple, if( email.indexOf('@thisdomainonly') > 0)

Comment: If this is about security this is dangerous, as one could easily create a subdomain with @thisdomainonly.com.myrealdomain.com

Answer (score 5):

Modifying your function, you'd use something like this:

```
function validateEmail(email)
{
    var splitted = email.match("^(.+)@thisdomainonly\.com$");
    if (splitted == null) return false;
    if (splitted[1] != null)
    {
        var regexp_user = /^\"?[\w-_\.]*\"?$/;
        if (splitted[1].match(regexp_user) == null) return false;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But a more efficient version would be:

```
function validateEmail(email){
    return /^\"?[\w-_\.]*\"?@thisdomainonly\.com$/.test(email);        
}
```

Comment: `test` is a more appropriate choice than `match`, but `indexOf` is likely best in regard to speed.

Comment: True, but indexOf will only check for the existance of the required domain, while test will also validate the local part.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me. i also tried appending the regexp in my inline validation but it is not working. do you have any idea why?

Comment: like if i input gibberish email, asdas@fgd.wqe for example, it still accepts the input. same as for the indexOf

Comment: That seems odd. Can you update your question with the new code you're using?

Comment: what do you mean, 'code'? including the html? that is the function for my html.

Comment: Ok. At which point in your HTML or JavaScript code does the validateEmail function actually get called? How does your Validator object know to use your custom validateEmail function to validate emails?

Comment: called the external scrpit in the html form and tried to use onclick="validateEmail();" in my submit button

Comment: frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req","Please enter your Email Address");
 frmvalidator.addValidation("email","maxlen=50");
 frmvalidator.addValidation("email","email");  <This is my validator for the email. am i missing something here?

Comment: I don't know which Validator you're using, so I can't give you exact details, but you will need to tell the validator to use your custom function somehow. You need to look up the documentation for this validator, or ask a specific question about that.

Comment: it seems like i havent included the function yet. what i have are validation descriptors only.

Answer (score 2):

How about a simple indexOf checking:

```
        function checkEmail(email, domainName){
            if(email.indexOf(domainName) > 0)
                if((email.indexOf(domainName) + domainName.length) == email.length){
                    //do regex checking if any
                    return true;
                }

            alert('Please enter a valid email for : '+ domainName)
            return false;
        }
```