# How to validate email address match with website domain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I have 2 input fields on my form: email and website

How do I use JQuery to validate the email address domain must matched with the website domain?

For example: if website is http://example.com or with www or without http:// or without http://www.
Then the email address field must be user@example.com

Here is my form https://jsfiddle.net/zm7e8r7p/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {

var val = $("#website").val();
var myString = val.substr(val.indexOf("http://") + 7);

var emailString = $("#email").val();
var myEmail = emailString.substr(emailString.indexOf("@")+1);

if (myString == myEmail){
$( "span" ).text( "Validated..." ).show();
event.preventDefault();
}else{
$( "span" ).text( "Not valid!" ).show();
event.preventDefault();

}

});
});
```

Comment: Try removing the protcol and www from the URL before comparing, e.g. [`.replace(/https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?/, "");`](https://jsfiddle.net/a3gbto41/)

Comment: You can  find right  answer in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13908877/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-from-a-specific-domain

Comment: @YolloPain: there is no answer for this question there.

Comment: Read second answer

Comment: If the url is `http://mysubdomain1.mysubdomain2.mydomain.name` ?

Comment: @Wiktor-Stribiżew your solution won't work if the website URL is like http://example.com/test/test.html

Comment: Yes, I know, Gabriel's will. Right? Test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use URL regex by [Crockford](http://www.coderholic.com/javascript-the-good-parts/)

Getting only last two parts of domain name is optional, you can use it if you want to convert `ww2.mobile.gmail.com` into `gmail.com`. This logic will affect domain names like `.co.in` as @samanime points out

```js
var parse_url = /^(?:([A-Za-z]+):)?(\/{0,3})([0-9.\-A-Za-z]+)(?::(\d+))?(?:\/([^?#]*))?(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?$/;
var url = 'www.mobile.ora.co.in:80/goodparts?q#fragment';

var result = parse_url.exec(url);

var hostName = result[3];

console.log("host name: ", hostName);

lastTwo = hostName.split('.');
lastTwo = lastTwo.length>2?lastTwo.slice(Math.max(lastTwo.length - 2, 1)) : lastTwo;
onlyMainDomain = lastTwo.join('.');

console.log('only main domain:', onlyMainDomain);

var email = "someone@ora.co.in";

var emailDomain = email.split('@')[1];

console.log('email domain:', emailDomain);

console.log("valid?" , emailDomain === onlyMainDomain);

//check if email domain is a child of hostName

emailDomainRev = emailDomain.split('.').reverse();
hostNameRev = hostName.split('.').reverse();
var emailDomainIsChildOfHostName = true;

if(emailDomainRev.length > hostNameRev.length){
  emailDomainIsChildOfHostName = false;
  }
else{
  emailDomainIsChildOfHostName = emailDomainRev.reduce(function(acc, item, index){
     return acc && (item === hostNameRev[index]);
  },true);
  }
console.log("email domain is a child of host name:", emailDomainIsChildOfHostName);
```

Comment: You're assuming that only the last two bits of the email make if valid. This wouldn't work for things like `example.co.jp`, and you can also technically have emails off of a sub-domain, like `me@sub.example.com`.

Comment: Yes, That is correct. I wonder what all requirements OP have! Anyway the full domain name is available from where he can split with `.` and process as he wish.

Comment: Thanks, out of all solutions, this one is the best and works for my case so far.

Comment: @delphiman I have added a solution to check if email domain is a child of host name, it covers cases like domains with `.co.in` as well. Also it validates to true if host name is `www.mobile.gmail.com` and email is `x@gmail.com` or `x@mobile.gmail.com`

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a simple JavaScript process to validate email with your domain name.**

```
function ValidateEmail(email) {
  var re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/; /*Regular expression for valid email*/
  return re.test(email);   /*Return `true` if valid, Otherwise return `false`*/
}

var domain = 'www.example@example.com';
var email  ='emaxple@example.com';

if(ValidateEmail(email)){
  email  = email.split('@');                     /* Split email after `@` Sign*/
  email  = email[1]                              /*After split, `email[0]=emaxple, email[1]=emaxple.com`*/
  domain = domain.split('').reverse().join('');  /*Now `domain = moc.elpmaxe@elpmaxe.www`*/
  email  = email.split('').reverse().join('');   /*Now `email = moc.elpmaxe*/
  email  = email + '@';                          /*Now `email = moc.elpmaxe@`*/
  if(domain.indexOf(email)==0){                  /*If only return `0` then valid, Otherwise Invalid*/
    /*Valid with your domain*/
  }else{
    /*Doesn't match with your domain*/
  }
}else{
    /*Invalid Email*/
}
```

Comment: `"moc.elpmaxe@elpmaxe.www".indexOf('moc.el') === 0` ,you will have to split at `.` and compare each.

Comment: Now I updated my code with `email = email + '@';`, So, Now no more duplicate combination. Thanks @sabithpocker

Answer (score 0):

I've added the regular expression Wiktor suggested with a minor change to accept url without protocol.

Your code would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#target").submit(function(event) {
        var website = $("#website").val();
        var websiteDomain = website.replace(/^(https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?/, "");

        var email = $("#email").val();
        var emailDomain = email.substr(email.indexOf("@")+1);

        $("span").text(websiteDomain === emailDomain ? "Valid!" : "Not valid!" ).show()

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a tricky part to your question. Technically, you can have a domain with any number of parts. For example: `this.is.a.valid.domain.com`

With the new custom top-level domains, it can get even trickier, since they make it possible to have all kinds of crazy combinations and lengths. For example: `this.is.also.a.valid.name.on.the.top.level.cake`

Looks nothing like a domain, but if you owned the top-level domain `cake`, you could make it happen.

So, you can't really trim off the sub-domain and ensure that `www.example.com` results in an email `@example.com`. However, you can tell if it's on at least `@www.example.com`, `@example.com` or `@com`, which could all be valid. (In reality, you couldn't have one on any of the controlled top-level domains, but it's probably good to allow it for those rare cases.)

This is why most websites require you to click a link in an email sent to you to validate your URL.

Using the above criteria I just described, you can do it with this:

```
var website = "http://www.example.com"; // website from form
var email = "me@example.com"; // email from form
var emailDomain = email.split('@')[1];
var websiteDomain = website.match(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?([^\/]+)/)[1];
var isValidEmail = (websiteDomain || '').lastIndexOf(emailDomain) === (websiteDomain || '').length - (emailDomain || '').length;
```

`isValidEmail` will then contain `true` if it is a valid match, or `false` if it isn't.

I've added checks for if something fails above so it won't throw an error if one of the above parts are bad. If you're giving an invalid website, `websiteDomain` will be `undefined`. Likewise for a completely invalid email, `emailDomain` will be `undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I update your code. I give you the link here 
https://jsfiddle.net/zm7e8r7p/5/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $( "#target" ).submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var emailString = $("#email").val();
      //cut rule by @
      var afterAt = emailString.split('@');

      var val = $("#website").val();
      var myString = val.substr(-(afterAt[1].length));

      console.log(afterAt[1].length);

      if (myString == afterAt[1]){
       console.log('works');return

      }else{
        console.log('not');return
      };
    });
});
```

Comment: It won't work if I enter a domain like this http://example.com/test/test/html and email is like this user@example.com