# java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 12

Tags: java, regex, email-validation

I am new to regEx. I need to validate email using java. I have created regEx for email validation by hardcoding the domain name. But the domain name should be dynamic. I have passed the domain name as a parameter. But I don't know how to pass parameter in regEx.

But I tried this code, then I got the error "**java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 12**". I have followed some answers but it doesn't help for me. From those answers I understood about repetition quantifier. Can you tell me what I am missing here and how to solve this issue?

```
public static boolean validateEmail(String email, String domainName) {
      pattern = Pattern.compile("^([\\w-\\.]+)@ {"+ domainName +"}" , Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
  }
```

Comment: You can use the solution from another question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40162591/how-to-validate-email-address-match-with-website-domain

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best Java email address validation method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624581/what-is-the-best-java-email-address-validation-method)

Comment: Best is probably to first validate that you have a syntactically correct email address (which is hard to get right, especially using regex), then check that it ends with `@domainName`.

Comment: @Didier L, I have validated by hardcoding the domain name like ```^([\\w-\\.]+)@(example.com | example.uk | example.co.in | example.edu.in )$. Since I am new to regEx, I don't know how to pass parameter in regEx. Now I learned and fixed.

Comment: Thank you Didier L and @Madina Saidova for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{` and `}` have meaning in regex, namely for specifying how often the character before it can repeat. E.g. `a{5}` matches `aaaaa`.

If you want to use curly braces in regex, you should escape them like `\\{` and `\\}`.

But that's not what you need for passing this as a parameter — it will just be literal text at that point. If you want to only match that literal domain, you could do `Pattern.compile("^([\\w-\\.]+)@" + domainName, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)`.